# Is there a way of receiving IO outside of main in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, io, program-entry-point, io-monad, do-notation

It may be a dumb question but I got an error when I try to get an input outside of the `main` function:

```
menu2Players :: String -> String -> (String, String)
menu2Players player1 player2 = do
    putStrLn("Qual o nome do primeiro jogador?\n")
    player1 <- getLine
    putStrLn("Qual o nome do segundo jogador?\n")
    player2 <- getLine
    return (player1, player2)
```

The error I got

> The IO action ‘main’ is not defined in module ‘Main’

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Your function actually returns a value of type `IO (String, String)`, so your type signature will cause an error. The lack of `main` is an entirely separate issue, but if you try to actually compile a file rather than just load it into GHCi, it needs to have a `main` value.

Comment: The program has a main but I want to return this function to another function

Comment: Well, that shouldn't be a problem. It must be a function (or, _action_) of `IO` type, though.

Comment: The code you posted and the error presented are unrelated.

Comment: `return` in Haskell is not the same `return` you'll find in other languages. It's a function, not a keyword, and as such has no effect on control flow. [Quick demonstration](https://tio.run/##TY6xDoJAEER7vmJKLeiMBdFYU1FYWBNYZOOxR469cH79eQhBt5p9mbxMX08vMibGznpXuTsHFAXKCqVo9mNXtDZDOkfqneC05DzHg42B9jyh89IoWwEFVvAwUMu1knnDj4lORCzPtWpY6PZvO2@2ymFehEnQWFEWT1CLnlzqZ0PNso07HNdvnxVwybHP/aLRsShCjB8)

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell, if you want to do IO in a function, it needs to return `IO`.

```
menu2Players :: String -> String -> IO (String, String)
menu2Players player1 player2 = do
    putStrLn "Qual o nome do primeiro jogador?\n"
    player1 <- getLine
    putStrLn "Qual o nome do segundo jogador?\n"
    player2 <- getLine
    return (player1, player2)
```

The details of why you need to return `IO` are a little tricky, but you can learn about it here: http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output

Answer (score 0):

(a bit late, but...) The code that worked, I just neeed the IO return.

```
menu2Players = do
    putStrLn "Qual o nome do primeiro jogador?\n"
    player1 <- getLine
    putStrLn "Qual o nome do segundo jogador?\n"
    player2 <- getLine
    return (player1, player2)
```